# ListView paging in android

Tags: android, listview, paging

How do I make paging like this for my ListView in android :

```
<< LAST   Page 1 Of 5   NEXT >>
```

I have been googling and haven't found any solution, please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Do some google before ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one demo try this >

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/

[How can I implement paging in listview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553437/how-can-i-implement-paging-in-listview-in-android)

Comment: @lichienmine +1 I use it and if you will be needed to implement it with HttpRequests or some other help. Please tell

Answer (score 2):

Listview with paging examples

[Simple-View Pager](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/10/simple-viewpager-for-android.html)

[Android pagination sample](https://github.com/paulononaka/Android-PaginationLayoutSample)

[Pagination for listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465978/pagination-for-listview-in-android)

[Endless adapter for listview and Paging](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/03/endless-apapter-in-android-listview.html)